# Fastest way to transpose 16 word array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance

I have the following code:

```
void shuffle_words(WORD_TYPE* _state) 
{
    WORD_TYPE temp[DATA_SIZE];

    temp[7]  = _state[0];
    temp[12] = _state[1];
    temp[14] = _state[2];
    temp[9]  = _state[3];
    temp[2]  = _state[4];
    temp[1]  = _state[5];
    temp[5]  = _state[6];
    temp[15] = _state[7];
    temp[11] = _state[8];
    temp[6]  = _state[9];
    temp[13] = _state[10];
    temp[0]  = _state[11];
    temp[4]  = _state[12];
    temp[8]  = _state[13];
    temp[10] = _state[14];
    temp[3]  = _state[15];

    memcpy_s(_state, temp, DATA_SIZE * WORD_SIZE);
}


int prp(WORD_TYPE* data, WORD_TYPE key) 
{
    shuffle_words(data);
    key = round_function<14, 15>(data, key);
    key = round_function<13, 14>(data, key);
    key = round_function<12, 13>(data, key);
    key = round_function<11, 12>(data, key);
    key = round_function<10, 11>(data, key);
    key = round_function<9, 10>(data, key);
    key = round_function<8, 9>(data, key);
    key = round_function<7, 8>(data, key);
    key = round_function<6, 7>(data, key);
    key = round_function<5, 6>(data, key);
    key = round_function<4, 5>(data, key);
    key = round_function<3, 4>(data, key);
    key = round_function<2, 3>(data, key);
    key = round_function<1, 2>(data, key);
    key = round_function<0, 1>(data, key);
    key = round_function<15, 0>(data, key);
    return key;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a faster way to perform the shuffle_words operation. I have seen questions about matrix transposition, but those appear to be focused on situations where the matrix is either large or multidimensional.

My array will always be 16 words in size, and the prp function will be applied multiple times on the same array, one immediately after another. This leads me to believe simply accessing elements in the transposed order without actually transposing them is an option.

The round_function already writes data to the array, if it would be more efficient to move the shuffle into that it would be acceptable. Here is the code for that, in case it's needed:

```
template <int left_index, int right_index> 
WORD_TYPE round_function(WORD_TYPE* state, WORD_TYPE key) 
{
    WORD_TYPE left, right;
    left = state[left_index];
    right = state[right_index];

    key ^= right;
    right = rotate_left<ROTATION_AMOUNT>(right + key + left_index);
    key ^= right;

    key ^= left;
    left += right >> (BIT_WIDTH / 2);
    left ^= rotate_left<(left_index % BIT_WIDTH) ^ ROTATION_AMOUNT>(right);
    key ^= left;

    state[left_index] = left;
    state[right_index] = right;
    return key;
}
```

I thought of supplying a destination index to round_function, but doing so overwrites bytes that have yet to be operated on, which destroys the data at the destination index.

What is the most efficient way to perform the word transposition step? 
Is it possible to efficiently perform shuffle_words without temporary storage and `memcpy`? Will the compiler optimize this for me if I leave it as is?

edit:

For a sample input of 16 null words, I got the following output:

```
5390936987981438580
7289498000187791405
11630888819098945478
4862561973623181657
11364775727483781365
1302861686580238483
10934483497681452460
376472396741801
17443576244438476890
17213444377027086447
15287741771379858051
16772715748200046576
6216997191100954620
16389751604649919423
2033403819063771136
14517213842436349075
```

I used these #defines:

```
#define ROTATION_AMOUNT 41
#define BIT_WIDTH 64
#define DATA_SIZE 16
typedef unsigned long long WORD_TYPE;
```

I am ok if functionality is modified slightly if an increase in efficiency can be obtained.

Comment: You cannot ask for *"faster"* without naming your platform. C++ doesn't make any performance guarantees.

Comment: Could you provide a sample input with the desired output?

Comment: What were your measures whith which specific input? This _"question"_ can't be answered consciously and verifiable.

Comment: I am a python programmer and not terribly familiar with C/C++. Please be forgiving if there are obvious mistakes or If I neglected to provide certain information that is otherwise required. What exactly does "target platform" mean? OS and exact CPU model? Why the downvote? How is this question not appropriate for the site? @FirstStep give me a minute and I will include example input/output in the question; However, if it can be done more efficiently but changes the functionality only slightly, I am ok with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

```
void shuffle_words(WORD_TYPE* _state) {

    WORD_TYPE temp = _state[0];

    _state[0] = _state[11];
    _state[11] = _state[8];
    _state[8] = _state[13];
    _state[13] = _state[10];
    _state[10] = _state[14];
    _state[14] = _state[2];
    _state[2] = _state[4];
    _state[4] = _state[12];
    _state[12] = _state[1];
    _state[1] = _state[5];
    _state[5] = _state[6];
    _state[6] = _state[9];
    _state[9] = _state[3];
    _state[3] = _state[15];
    _state[15] = _state[7];
    _state[7] = temp;
}
```

Comment: IInspectable, FirstStep, and that other person are all wrong.  This will run faster on your platform.  I guarantee it.

Comment: This does appear to provide a 10% throughput increase for me (win8/intel celeron). I'm going to wait to mark it as an answer though, to see if there are even better ways. I didn't unit test it yet though, let me do that too.

Comment: @EllaRose There is no doubt this will be faster, all of the assignments are the end result so no need for the big `memcpy_s` at the end. There may be other improvements by reordering the data access to make it as linear as possible.

Comment: Since it's just 16 words, it will fit in the L1 cache on most processors, and. the order of operations probably doesn't matter. (I'm assuming an optimizing compiler keeps temp in a register). There are shuffle patterns (permutations) that involve multiple "cycles", where temp would have to be used for the start and end of each "cycle", but for the given shuffle pattern, it's just one cycle. Assuming temp is in a register, then multiple cycles still only involve 16 memory reads and 16 memory writes (all of which should fit in L1 cache).

Comment: Sorry, -1. Code-only answers are pretty useless. Unless you explain, why this is faster, on any platform in the universe, this isn't helpful at all. Not sure why you claim that [my statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645777/fastest-way-to-transpose-16-word-array#comment64674444_38645777) is wrong, when it is provably correct. And if you are indeed targeting an Intel Celeron, you'd be using SSE (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`/`_mm_shuffle_epi32`) and easily have a 200% performance gain, vs. 10%.

Comment: Don't be bitter IInspectable. The reason I say your answer was wrong was because you stated, unequivocally, that the question was unanswerable yet I answered it.  My answer was concise and correct.  My efficiency guarantee was verified by OP.  I have 19 years of experience with C++ and various compilers.  I can't even imagine a compiler that would result in _more_ CPU cycles for my code compared to the original code.

Comment: My code uses less memory on the stack, performs the same 16 word moves, and has only 1 additional word move in place of the entire call to memcpy. It doesn't matter if the word size is 16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits, it doesn't matter if the CPU busses are 16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits or any combination thereof.  My answer is platform independent.  In the original post they just asked if there was a faster way.  My answer wasn't code only, my answer clearly stated "Yes!" before presenting the faster code.

Comment: You probably missed the title, it's asking for the *"fastest"* way, not just faster. And my *"answer"* is a *"comment"*. Since you cannot exhaustively prove, that your code will run faster using any C++ compiler targeting any hardware platform, you cannot claim, that it were unequivocally faster, even less so fastest. The question, as asked, cannot be answered, unless you count provably incorrect answers (like yours) as answers. I don't. And I already hinted to an implementation that might be a lot faster given a particular platform. As I said, C++ doesn't make any performance promises.

Comment: *"My code uses less memory on the stack"* - Your code is C or C++. Neither prescribe how objects with automatic storage duration are to be implemented. Your claim about *"less stack memory"* is completely unfounded (in the context of the question, as asked).

Comment: [sigh...] I answered the question I read in the original, unedited, post asking if there was a "faster" way. True, my claim about less stack used is based on a few compilers I know for CPUs which have a small number of registers. There are two likely spots for the compiler to put local variables: purely in registers or on the stack. It's probably moot in terms of speed how much stack is used anyways because the CPU will have constant-time instruction to allocate local storage on stack. You say my answer is useless? Funny, because OP demonstrated a speed improvement with it.

Comment: Code-only answers **are** useless (and an introductory *"Yes!"* as the sole prose doesn't make it not code-only). Whether the code improves performance on some undisclosed platform, using an undisclosed compiler, with undisclosed compiler settings is irrelevant, when the question (mind you, the original, unedited) carries the title *"Fastest way to do xyz"*. The code in question can easily be sped up by a factor of 4, using AVX vector instructions, for example, and that invalidates your answer. It simply isn't the *"fastest"* way, as requested.

Comment: "I would like to know if there is a faster way to perform the shuffle_words operation." -  Ella Rose

Comment: *"Fastest way to transpose 16 word array"* - Ella Rose.